# How to use 'andFilterWhere' with 'like' for integer fields in Yii2?

Tags: php, mongodb, activerecord, yii2

I try to make a filter for integer field in mongoDB using `andFilterWhere`.

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'code', $this->code ]);
```

This method work fine for String value but for integer value doesn't work. How to use this method for integer fields?

Comment: Why you are using LIKE for integer. Direct use = operator

Comment: I have integer field  with code and I need to filter values in gridView 
which contain needed part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example helps me to solve my issue:

```
 if ($this->code)
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                '$where' => '/' . $this->code . '/.test(this.code')'
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a  string try an implicit conversion or an esplicit casting  or a function call for the var

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'code', $this->code .'' ]);
```

-

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'code', (string)$this->code  ]);
```

-

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'code', strval($this->code ) ]);
```

eventually convet you val before the sue

```
$my_value = (string)$this->code ;

$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'code', $my_value ]);
```

then if 'code' is the interger you can try

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like',  'CAST(code as CHAR(50))', $my_value ]);
```

otherwise you can avoid andFilterWhere  and use literal andWhere

```
if (isset($this->code) {
  $query->andWhere(' CAST(code as CHAR(50)) like ' . $this->code; 
}
```

Comment: In my case  `'code'` is integer and `$my_value` is String.

Comment: I have update the anwer .. this should solve your problem ..let me know

Comment: Sorry, but this solution is not working correctly. `CAST` uses in mySql

Comment: I'm sorry you are not using mysql ... but the meaning is similar ..if there are casting function or implicit   conversion in mondodb you can apply in the andWhere literal  filter ... otherwise .. if you can change the source there are not solutions ..

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'code', $this->code ? (int)$this->code: null]);
```

Comment: Please explain why the ternary operator is used, and wy you cast to an int. Code only answer are not always very useful.

Answer (score -2):

With Or

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['or', ['like', 'code', $this->code ]]);
```

With and

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['and', ['like', 'code', $this->code ]]);
```

Comment: Sorry, this method works correctly only with String values

Comment: Thanks, but i just gave the idea how you can achieve with integer.